# Polymer draggable with interact.js / shadowDOM selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, polymer, shadow-dom, interact.js

I am attempting to use the interact.js library to create a draggable Polymer event.  I know there exists a core-drag-drop element, I would like to use interact.js.  I am attempting to get the first example working by passing in a class to the interact object.

```
interact('.draggable').draggable({....
```

This doesn't work in Polymer as it has to access the elements shadowDOM.  I have tried the following selectors:

```
"custom-elem::shadow .draggable"
":host-context(.draggable)"
":host(.draggable)"
"custom-elem /deep/ .draggable"
"drop::shadow .draggable"
"custom-elem::shadow .draggable"
```

All return null.

I also attempted to assign and pass a reference to a single object which has the .draggable class:

```
var x = this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".draggable");
interact(x).draggable({....
```

This does not work as well.
Any advice?

EDIT:

```
<polymer-element name="custom-elem">
<template>
<div class="draggable"></div>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: What does the shadow tree look like? If the `.draggable` element is a shadow element, then `:host(.draggable)` and `:host-context(.draggable)` aren't correct.

Comment: It is. The .draggable element resides under the custom elements template. Sorry I will add the tree

Comment: With the latest version of interact.js selectors don't reach elements in shadow DOMs and using the elements directly causes throws errors. I'm the author of interact.js and I'm working on a few fixes to handle shadow DOMs better.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for taking time to respond!  I will continue to check for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.2.3 of interact.js you should be able to interact with elements Shadow DOMs. The implementation may change and there are some issues to be aware of:

1. `Element.matches` seems to always fail with deep/shadow-piercing selectors. For example, try running this on https://polymer-project.org:

   `var selector = 'paper-button::shadow *';`
   `document.querySelector(selector).matches(selector); // false`

   So such selectors won't work with interact.js.
2. `:host`, `::shadow`, `::content` selectors cause errors if used with the Shadow DOM polyfill

In your case, since the element you want to target is in the ShadowDOM and deep selectors don't work, you should add a more specific class to the element. For example:

```html
<polymer-element name="custom-elem">
<template>
<div class="custom-elem-draggable"></div>
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

```js
interact('.custom-elem-draggable').draggable(/* ... */);
```

That should work with both the native and polyfilled Shadow DOM.

Comment: Your "this version" link appears broken.  Could you update? Thanks!